# Ckeditor inserttext not inserting text between existing tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to use ckeditor function "insertText" outside of ckeditor and trying to insert text through it:

ckeditor_instance.insertText('%%Firstname%%')

But if i already applied the font style to any text and then run above function between the tags then font style does not apply to new text:

**Example:**

**Before inserting '%%Firstname%%':**

`<span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;">Look forward to more exciting emails coming soon.</span>`

**After Inserting above text after more through javascript:**

`<span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;">Look forward to more </span> %%Firstname%% <span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;">exciting emails coming soon.</span>`

You can see span tags are automatically closing and opening so style not applying to '%%Firstname%%'.

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using insertText and not insertHtml? This result is rather impossible with insertText unless some other things happen.

Comment: Yes, i am sure i am using insertText not insertHtml.

Comment: Oh..... yes you are absolutely right somewhere other ckeditor function insertText override with insertHtml. Now it is fixed.